# blob.getBinaryStream independently closes

Tags: java, jdbc, blob, ojdbc

I have a java method which is fetching blob from oracle database (I'm using ojdbc8.jar). This method writes blob to OutputStream (for client):

```
// OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();  // earlier
// Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("data_binary");  // earlier

    int length;
    int bufSize = 4096;
    byte buffer[] = new byte[bufSize];
    try (InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream()) {
        while ((length = is.read(buffer, 0, bufSize)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            out.flush();
        }
        out.flush();
    }
```

and  returns InputStream (for cache):

```
return blob.getBinaryStream();
```

And when I'm trying (on the other class) to write this InputStream to the disk:

```
    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fileOnTheDisk)) {
        IOUtils.copy(blobIS, os);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm gettting Exceptions:

```
java.io.IOException: Closed Connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream.needBytes(OracleBlobInputStream.java:204)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBufferedStream.readInternal(OracleBufferedStream.java:169)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBufferedStream.read(OracleBufferedStream.java:143)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBufferedStream.read(OracleBufferedStream.java:132)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1025)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:999)
at ru.miit.databasereader.OracleDatabaseReader.getbo(OracleDatabaseReader.java:262)
at ru.miit.contentservlet.ContentGetter.getObject(ContentGetter.java:85)
at ru.miit.contentservlet.ContentServlet.doGet(ContentServlet.java:131)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:409)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
at oracle.sql.BLOB.getDBAccess(BLOB.java:1122)
at oracle.sql.BLOB.getBytes(BLOB.java:348)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream.needBytes(OracleBlobInputStream.java:181)
... 31 more
```

I need a solution  how to write this `blob.getBinaryStream()` to disk on the other class and to know what's the problem.

I tried to write this blob stream to disk in this (fetching) method and I didn't get an exceptins. And only when I return this stream to the other class, I have an exceptions.

**UPDATED**

Full code. DiskCache:

```
public class DiskCache {

public void put(final String location, final String name, final InputStream blobIS, OutpuStream servletOS) {

    DatabaseReader databaseReader = new DatabaseReader ();

    BinaryObject binaryobject = databaseReader.getBinaryDataByImageId(imageId, servletOS);

    File fileOnTheDisk = new File(location + name);

    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fileOnTheDisk)) {
        IOUtils.copy(binaryobject.getIS(), os);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

DatabaseReader:

```
public class DatabaseReader{

public Connection getConnection() throws NamingException, SQLException {

    Context initialContext = null;
    try {
        initialContext = new InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup(DATASOURCE_NAME);
        OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection) dataSource.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
        return connection;
    } finally {
        if (initialContext != null){
            initialContext.close();
        }
    }

}
    public BinaryObject getBinaryDataByImageId(final String imageId, OutputStream osServlet) throws SQLException, NamingException, IOException{

     String sqlQuery = "***";

     BinaryObject binaryObject = null;
     try (Connection connection = getConnection();
            OraclePreparedStatement preparedStatement = (OraclePreparedStatement) connection
                    .prepareStatement(sqlQuery)) {
        try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {

            resultSet.next();
            Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("blob_data");
            writeToStream(blob, osServlet); 
            binaryObject = new BinaryObject(imageId, blob.getBinaryStream());

        }
      }
      return binaryObject;
    }


    public void writeToStream(Blob blobData, OutputStream out) throws IOException, SQLException {

    int length;
    int bufSize = 4096;
    byte buffer[] = new byte[bufSize];
    try (InputStream is = blobData.getBinaryStream()) {
        while ((length = is.read(buffer, 0, bufSize)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            out.flush();
        }
        out.flush();

    }

}
}
```

JNDI:

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/database" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" 
    maxIdle="30" maxWait="1000"
    username="***" 
    password="***"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin***"/>
```

Comment: @DodgyCodeException, is there only one stream? It means when I'm calling `blob.getBinaryStream()` the second time, I'm calling the same stream which had already been read?

Comment: You may want to show the full code. For example, for `Blob`, the API doc states: _"A `Blob` object is valid for the duration of the transaction in which is [sic] was created."_. And the error itself would seem to indicate that you even closed the entire connection that created the blob.

Comment: @Adey I see what you mean. I've deleted my previous comment as it was nonsense in this context.

Comment: This still isn't the full code, as you don't show the connection setup and transaction lifetime. In any case, give the code shown, I suspect the connection is closed by the time you do something with the blob.

Comment: @Adey You still don't show how you obtain the connection, and what you do with it at the end of the method, so it still does not demonstrate that this is **not** caused by you trying to use the blob after the transaction or even connection ended.

Comment: And that code clearly shows you close the connection... and that in turn closes the blob. If you want to do anything with the blob, you should do it **before** you close the connection.

Comment: Don't flush inside loops.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, You improved my knowledge about jdbc! tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blob should be read only once, within every `ResultSet.next` step. After the result set is closed (and it should be closed), and after the blob's input stream is read (closing the stream too) you are out of luck.

If you want to serve the client fast, and store a duplicate in a cache you would need to do both at the same time:

```
// OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();  // earlier
// Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("data_binary");  // earlier
// OutputStream cacheOut
final int bufSize = 4096;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
int length;
try (InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream()) {
    while ((length = is.read(buffer, 0, bufSize)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        out.flush();
        cacheOut.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    out.flush();
    cacheOut.close();
}
```

Anything else would be a memory intensive task.

Comment: Thank you for a full answer! I think I'll use your advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
    BinaryObject binaryObject = null;
    try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
        resultSet.next();
        Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("data_binary");
        writeToStream(blob, osServlet); 
        binaryObject = new BinaryObject(imageId, blob.getBinaryStream());

    }
    return binaryObject;
```

By using try-with-resources your [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) gets closed as soon as the scope was left, so trying to read from the BLOB's [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) leads to an error. You're writing the data to some other stream anyway, so in case this is a temporary file somewhere, you might use a [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) on that temporary file instead.

Comment: You mean, when I copy blob to OutputStream, I should copy to some `FileInputStream` and return it to DiskCache class?

Comment: @Adey I mean that `blob.getInputStream()` will give you an `InputStream` that is no longer valid after you leave the `try`-block. If you want to work with the data you get from the stream, you have to write it somewhere else (e.g. a temporary file) to be able to open in `InputStream` allowing you to read from it while the original `ResultSet`/`PreparedStatement` is already closed.

Comment: thx, but I think if I would have a lot of customer requests, app will require a lot of extra disk space.

Comment: This is only true when the statement was executed in auto-commit mode, as the lifetime of a blob is not (or should not be) tied to the result set, but to the transaction. In auto-commit, the result set close will lead to a commit, but otherwise the blob should still be open (until the transaction is committed, rolled back or the connection is closed). This is assuming that the driver does fully comply with the JDBC requirements for a blob.

Comment: @Adey Temporary files should only while they are useful, i.e. after it, the file should be deleted (don't rely on automatisms of the operating system, they seldom work reliably). If the data in the BLOB is not big, you can write them into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead and "reopen" it by creating a `ByteArrayInputStream` with the data coming from `toByetArray()`.